# can't connect to remote appfabric cache

Tags: caching, credentials, appfabric

I have installed Windows Server AppFabric. The cluster is running fine.
Now I try to remotely access the cache from an ASP.NET application. This does not work.
I get an error message saying the server rejected client authentication"

The message is clear, but I have no ideau how I can resolve it. I don't know how sending my credentials.

any idea?

---

### This is my conf

- a 2 servers cluster installed on VM on Windows Azure. the local server is my laptop
- I correctly set the virtual network and the VPN.
- Each server can access or ping each other, so I am sure the network works.
- The cluster is running and get-cache is OK
- I didn't forget to set endpoints on each cluster
- I created on all 3 servers this account: **appFabricAccount** with the same password.
- The account is local admin, this is a local account.

**Important**: this is on premises AppFabric, not Azure AppFabric. Azure is there only to host my VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding 'NT Authority\Network Service' to existing accounts using grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount and try? Since you are accessing it from outside local network , this might be required..

Comment: In domain joined machines, usually the machine connects to another machine using domain\system$ account. You could try adding machineName$ accounts as clients and retry.

Comment: my local PC is on a domain, but not the appFabric server

in fact I installed a local useer account on the asp.net server (appFabricAccount). this account exists the same on all other server. so I suspect I should use its credentials. But I have no ideau to pass the when connecting to the cache

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is solved.

I forgave to run the web application into an application pool running on the identity: appFabricAccount

I did it.

I still have an error, but this is a versionning problem. 
I consider the problem as resolved.